# How to reinstall IIS on windows 10?

Tags: iis, iis-10, windows-10-desktop

When I launch IIS on my windows 10 machine, it does not list DefaultAppPool under Application Pools and there is no Default Web Site. How can I reinstall IIS to have these defaults back? I tried to uncheck the below and restarted my machine hoping that it would unintall IIS. Then I checked it back to reinstall. But it did not show the default web site and defaultapppool.

Internet Information Services -> Web Management Tools -> IIS Management Console

Thanks for any suggestions to reinstall IIS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can uninstall iis completely, and then reinstall it, about how to uninstall iis completely you can remove the following roles:

- Web Server (IIS) under tab "Server Roles" in Server Manager
- And Windows Process Activation Service in "Features" tab in Server Manager

  Attention: A server restart is necessary after the uninstallation.
- Then delete the files or rename the folder (preferred) for C:\inetpub
  and C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv.

Here the key step is to uninstall Windows Process Activation Service (WAS). This is the service responsible for managing application pool configuration, creating and managing lifetime of worker process for HTTP and other protocols. Once WAS uninstalled, we can safely remove the configuration files located under C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv to finally make a clean uninstallation of IIS.

To reinstall IIS, just to follow the same steps: add Web Server (IIS) as well as WAS.

More information about how to perform a clean reinstallation of IIS you can refer to this link: [How to perform a clean reinstallation of IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/archive/blogs/friis/how-to-perform-a-clean-reinstallation-of-iis)

Comment: I am trying to do it on my development machine which is windows 10. Can I still follow the same steps? I dont see server manager from start menu. Thank you!

Comment: @Jyina For anyone else wondering you just go to `Turn Windows features on or off` and select IIS and Windows Process Activation Service. Continue following samwus steps.