# While doing a restore backup with appcmd, iis crashed and cannot be fixed

Tags: iis, backup, restore

My  IIS was crashed - Services are not starting due to the following changes done by me in the IIS due to unaware of version migration.

I have taken the back of IIS 7.5 from Windows Server 2008 R2 using the below command

%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe add backup "mySite20210818"

and restored the backup in IIS 8.5 in Windows server 2019 using the below command

%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe restore backup "mySite20210818"

Due to the above changes the IIS is not working and also i could able to start the IIS service itself...i tried to remove the role and then added the role still its not working..

When restoring, why doesn't it say not to install version incompatible, I have to install windows server 2019 again?

Please suggest solution. I will not use appcmd backup again.

what i tried

1. I copied the files from "C:\inetpub\history\CFGHISTORY_0000000001" into "%windir%\system32\inetsrv\Config".
2. iisreset /stop
3. iisreset /start

iisreset /start
The IIS Management Service or the World Wide Web Publishing Service or a dependent service failed to start. The service or dependent services may have encountered an error or been disabled during startup.

4. iisreset /status
   Status: IIS Management Service ( IISADMIN ): Stopped
   Status: Windows Process Activation Service (WAS): Stopped
   Status: Net.Pipe Listener Adapter ( NetPipeActivator ): Stopped
   Status: Net.Tcp Listener Adapter ( NetTcpActivator ): Stopped
   Status: World Wide Web Publishing Service ( W3SVC ): Stopped
5. Removed iis from roles and reinstalled. But it doesn't come off completely.

[image]

Regards

Comment: Your backup/restore steps are invalid as they are not supposed for different machines (and Windows versions). You can only use tools like Web Deploy to migrate sites from one machine to another. For corrupt installation like that, your best option is to reinstall Windows (or full server restore from a backup snapshot).

Comment: I think it will if I can do a clean iis install. "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64051012/how-to-reinstall-iis-on-windows-10" 

I removed iis with this command, I read and did the steps for clean iis installation, but I cannot reinstall iis. If I can find an iis installer I guess it will.  Uninstall-WindowsFeature -Remove Web-Server

Comment: It is recommended to use IIS Easy Migration Tool(IEMT) to migrate IIS between different versions. It is easy to use. You can get it from [here](https://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2013/04/iis-easy-migration-tool-iemt).