# Getting "Illegal characters in path" popup error in IIS when trying to explore folders in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a strange situation in IIS. I do have ASP.NET projects configured for the IIS, but in one of the projects I simply can't navigate to its subfolders. When I click the > button to the right of the folder name, I get the popup error "Illegal characters in path".

I did check the basic settings and the advanced settings. Neither the Virtual Path has any illegal characters not the Physical Path has any illegal characters. I am a bit a confused, what should I do to resolve the error?

Thank you very much in advance, screen shot is below

[image]

Comment: I suggest you to reinstall your iis and try again, about how to reinstall iis you can refer to this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64051012/how-to-reinstall-iis-on-windows-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64051012/how-to-reinstall-iis-on-windows-10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. It turns out I had to check the Virtual Directories. Once I clicked the 'View Virtual Directories', I found that in one of the virtual directories there is malformed path

Comment: Mine transpired to be the script I made had a path ending with \ which caused the outside double quote to be included as part of the App's path - i.e. `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe add app /site.name:"Default Web Site" /path:/MyApp /physicalPath:"E:\Web\Content\"` - Removing the slash resolved it. Thanks to your "View Virtual Directories" suggestion, I did a similar thing albeit with "View Applications" and reviewing the paths.